# jquery : "force" the selected option to replace the placeholder "loading" in a select list

Tags: jquery, select, prop

i would like to show a "loading" message in a list, while my list is loading titles from Flickr.

I created a single `<option>` :

```
<select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
    <option>Loading...</option>
</select>
```

and my function with jquery :

```
$.when(preload_titles()).done(function(){
    $("#select-choice-1 option:eq(1)").prop("selectedIndex",1);
    $("#select-choice-1").change();
});
```

but i can't make the option at index 1 to be "selected" after the titles are loaded. Do you know how to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: Can you prepare a js-fiddle please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
prop("selectedIndex",1)
```

to

```
prop("selected", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "selected"

```
 $("#select-choice-1 option:eq(1)").prop("selected",true);
```